# How To Insert Header Logo in TCPDF?

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    include 'includes/session.php';
    
    $range = $_POST['date_range'];
    $ex = explode(' - ', $range);
    $from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($ex[0]));
    $to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($ex[1]));

    $sql = "SELECT *, SUM(amount) as total_amount FROM deductions";
    $query = $conn->query($sql);
    $drow = $query->fetch_assoc();
    $deduction = $drow['total_amount'];

    $from_title = date('M d, Y', strtotime($ex[0]));
    $to_title = date('M d, Y', strtotime($ex[1]));

    require_once('../tcpdf/tcpdf.php');  
    $pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);  
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);  
    $pdf->SetTitle('Payslip: '.$from_title.' - '.$to_title);  
    $pdf->SetHeaderData('', PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);  
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));  
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');  
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);  
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '10', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);  
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);  
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);  
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);  
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 11); 
    
    $pdf->AddPage(); 
    $contents = '';

    $sql = "SELECT *, SUM(num_hr) AS total_hr, attendance.employee_id AS empid, employees.employee_id AS employee FROM attendance LEFT JOIN employees ON employees.id=attendance.employee_id LEFT JOIN position ON position.id=employees.position_id WHERE date BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' GROUP BY attendance.employee_id ORDER BY employees.lastname ASC, employees.firstname ASC";

    $query = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        $empid = $row['empid'];
                      
        $casql = "SELECT *, SUM(amount) AS cashamount FROM cashadvance WHERE employee_id='$empid' AND date_advance BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'";
      
        $caquery = $conn->query($casql);
        $carow = $caquery->fetch_assoc();
        $cashadvance = $carow['cashamount'];

        $gross = $row['rate'] * $row['total_hr'];
        $total_deduction = $deduction + $cashadvance;
        $net = $gross - $total_deduction;

        $contents .= '
            
            <h2 align="center">MixWellWorld</h2>
        
            <h4 align="center">'.$from_title." - ".$to_title.'</h4>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
                <tr>
                <td width="25%" align="right">Company Name</td></tr>
            </table>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">             
               
               <tr>  
                    
                    <td width="25%" align="right">Employee Name: </td>
                    <td width="25%"><b>'.$row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname'].'</b></td>
                    <td width="25%" align="right">Rate per Hour: </td>
                    <td width="25%" align="right">'.number_format($row['rate'], 2).'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="25%" align="right">Employee ID: </td>
                    <td width="25%">'.$row['employee'].'</td>   
                    <td width="25%" align="right">Total Hours: </td>
                    <td width="25%" align="right">'.number_format($row['total_hr'], 2).'</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td></td> 
                    <td></td>
                    <td width="25%" align="right"><b>Gross Pay: </b></td>
                    <td width="25%" align="right"><b>'.number_format(($row['rate']*$row['total_hr']), 2).'</b></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td></td> 
                    <td></td>
                    <td width="25%" align="right">Deduction: </td>
                    <td width="25%" align="right">'.number_format($deduction, 2).'</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td></td> 
                    <td></td>
                    <td width="25%" align="right">Cash Advance: </td>
                    <td width="25%" align="right">'.number_format($cashadvance, 2).'</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td></td> 
                    <td></td>
                    <td width="25%" align="right"><b>Total Deduction:</b></td>
                    <td width="25%" align="right"><b>'.number_format($total_deduction, 2).'</b></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                    <td></td> 
                    <td></td>
                    <td width="25%" align="right"><b>Net Pay:</b></td>
                    <td width="25%" align="right"><b>'.number_format($net, 2).'</b></td> 
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br><hr>
        ';
    }
    $pdf->writeHTML($contents);  
    $pdf->Output('payslip.pdf', 'I');

?>
```

I want to add header logo in the PDF. I am unable to figure out how can I do it.

2ndly, When I add more tr or td, It doesn't display in PDF. If I add img tag to display logo it is also not working.

Could you please guide me how should I set a logo in it? Or how can I style the output?

Here is what I am getting in PDF so far.

[image: PDF Output]

Comment: It's been awhile since I've tinkered with TCPDF, but there is a `$pdf->addJpegFromFile(...)` function that could possibly help.

Comment: You need to extend the class. (Extend the TCPDF class to create custom Header and Footer) - see [official_reference](https://tcpdf.org/files/examples/example_003.phps)

Comment: I tried it earlier and it didn;t work. Do I need to set K_Path_Images directory? 

I am using xampp for this and my header logo is in "C:\xampp\htdocs\apsystem\images\payslip.png" 

If i need to set the directory could you please guide me how can i do it?

Comment: The image path should be relative, such as    `$img_file = './apsystem/images/payslip.png';` or  `$img_file = './images/payslip.png';` (depending on your setup)